# parent child relations

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best way of getting products assigned to child categories when the parent category is selected?

i.e If I select the top level category I'd like to get all the products in all the sub categories not just products assigned to the current level selected.

so selecting category 1 will return prod_id's 1 and 2. Selecting category 2 will return prod_id 2.

```
**category**
id parent_id name
1     0       Vegetables
2     1       Tomatoes
3     2       Yellow Tomatoes

**product_category**
prod_id cat_id
  1       1
  2       3

**products**
prod_id name
  1       Carrot
  2       Small Yellow Tomato
```

Comment: Can you display a sample output of the results that you are expecting?

Comment: @user813720 I don't understand, if you select category 1.. it should return products with category 1 or 2 (because the parent category is 1).. but you said it return prod_id 2, which has category 3..

Comment: cat3 has parent of cat2. so if you select cat2 it should get all products of cat2 and all products of any categories that are children of cat2. Hence my renaming of the products above. A yellow tomato is in the yellow tomato cat and is also a tomato and a vegetable.

Comment: @user813720 then my edited answer will work for you..

Answer (score 1):

is this query what you're looking for?

```
$query =<<<MYSQL
 SELECT `prod_id`
 FROM `produdct_category` 
  INNER JOIN `category` ON `product_category`.`cat_id` = `category`.`id`
 WHERE `category`.`parent_id` = {$selectedParentId}
MYSQL;
```

Updated question, updated answer:

```
$query =<<<MYSQL
 SELECT *
 FROM `produdcts` 
  INNER JOIN `produdct_category` ON `products`.`prod_id` = `produdct_category`.`prod_id`
  INNER JOIN `category` ON `product_category`.`cat_id` = `category`.`id`
 WHERE `category`.`id` = {$selectedCatId}
   OR `category`.`parent_id` = {$selectedCatId}
MYSQL;
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't know the parent_id only the category_id.

Comment: THanks for you answer, but as far as I can see that would only select two levels of hierarchy. It's actually the children category products that I need to find. I think this is probably easiest accomplished with recursive selects and php to find the category id's of all the children categories.

Comment: @user813720 now I understand what you want. how many levels do you want to search for child sub-categories? because maybe you need to change your architecture and face the problem from another point of view..

Comment: Ideally an infinite amount of levels but in practice probably only three or four. I will ask another question based on the best architecture for this problem.

Comment: question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441723/db-architecture-for-retrieving-items-stored-in-child-categories-from-parent-cate

Answer (score 0):

Correct the table names and choose fields you need to select first. Then do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` AS p
INNER JOIN `product_category` AS pc ON p.id = pc.prod_id
INNER JOIN `category` AS c ON pc.cat_id = c.id
WHERE `parent_id` = YOUR_VALUE_HERE
```